# How to make Okular play embedded video

Tags: latex, okular

So I create presentations using LaTeX and the Beamer class. This allows me to embed videos (.mp4, .avi, .gif) formats in my presentation. These seem to play well in full versions of acrobat reader but these videos DO NOT play in Okular.

Is there something else I should do to configure Okular? Is this a LaTeX question or a Ubuntu question? `;)`

**Code snippet to embed video in latex**

```
\documentclass[bookmarks=true]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=yellow, fg=black}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Slide Title Here}

    \centering
    \includemovie{6.5cm}{6.5cm}{./figures/Video.avi}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following worked for me:

1. Change the backend of Phonon (which is used by Okular to play videos) to the VLC one. For me it sufficed to install the respective package:

   ```
   sudo apt install phonon-backend-vlc
   ```

   On newer versions of Ubuntu, the crucial package is `phonon4qt5-backend-vlc`.
2. Use `multimedia` instead of `movie15`:

   ```
   \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{multimedia}

   \begin{document}
       \begin{frame}
           \movie[poster, height=6.5cm, width=6.5cm]{}{/figures/Video.avi}
       \end{frame}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Doesn't help. The videos are still not showing

Comment: @RubiShnol: It’s hard to help without any specifics, but this could be the symptoms of the EoL of Flash EoL – on which all multimedia embedding in PDFs is based.

Comment: It works in previous releases of Okular. They were okay, but crashed when exiting presentation mode (known bug). With the new one, 1.10, the videos are no longer playable. I embedded an mp4 not using flash (used `multimedia` package). Support of flash will end soon anyway

Comment: @RubiShnol: As far as I know, every embedding of multimedia content in PDFs is eventually based on Flash, including the `multimedia` package.

Comment: Not sure about that. What version of Okular are you using?

Comment: @RubiShnol: I am no expert on this, but my understanding is that this is not about the version of Okular, but about how multimedia embedding in PDFs works. See e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516029/28608).

Comment: Still, the older version gets it whereas the latest one doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Movie15 is actually absolete now. You'd better use media9, however chances are this also won't work since a lot of pdf-readers just won't play video's for security reasons.